# Relacionamento OneToMany unidirecional

Tags: java, aplicação-web

Ola, pessoal! Me ajudem!
Tenho um sistema financeiro e estou com dúvida no relacionamento de Usuario e Conta, conforme UML. Pelo que meu professor me falou, aqui temos que fazer um OneToMany em Usuario somente, mas percebi que conta ficou com chave estrangeira. Poderiam fazer como seria este relacionamento? Quando eu for criar o teste também crio Conta e seto os dados e depois crio Usuario e usuario.setConta(conta).
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Em Usuario tenho abaixo:**

@OneToMany(cascade=CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
@JoinColumn(name= "ID_USER", foreingkey = @ForeingKey(name="USER_CONTA_FK))
private List< Conta > contas;

E na classe Conta não defini nada, até mesmo porque me falaram que não defino, mas esta me parecendo que falta algo e no banco SQL DEVELOPER, a tabela conta está com uma coluna de ID_USUARIO... Como? não coloquei nada lá... ????

Obrigado e desculpe qualquer erro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O seu diagrama de classe me parece correto em relação ao relacionamento **Usuário -> Conta** a chave estrangeira DEVE existir na sua Classe *Conta* visto que segundo o seu sistema um usuário pode possuir **várias contas** então neste caso o Banco de Dados necessita de ter uma referência de qual **usuário** está vinculado àquela **conta**. 
O relacionamento unidirectional fara com que você consiga "acessar" a conta através apenas da classe *Usuario*, visto que o mapeamento está feito nesta classe, ou seja, você conseguirá obter uma lista de contas que o usuário está vinculado mas não ao contrário.

Como sua classe *Conta* é uma entidade ela deve possuir o mapeamento no JPA com tal anotação para ser mapeada, porém como o relacionamento que você deseja é unidirecional não é necessário que faça o **@ManyToOne** na classe Conta (que é o reverso do **@OneToMany**).

Caso tenha alguma outra dúvida estou à disposição!

Comment: Ola, Matheus! Obrigado! Então meu professor estava certo :)... Desculpa lhe atrapalhar, mas se puder me tirar mais uma dúvida ou mais umas :). A primeira é Quando crio um teste de conta, crio um banco e adiciono em conta e no banco SQL Develope a chave FK ID_USUARIO FICA null, ta certo?

Comment: Manda lá Rafael !

Comment: Estou com problemas para entender a questão de add conta. Como faço: BancoDAO bancoDAO = new BancoDAO(); Banco banco = new Banco(); banco = bancoDAO.buscaId(1L); E depois faço conta.setBanco(banco); Está certo? e o metodo esta no proximo comentário.

Comment: public Entidade buscarId(Long id) {
  try {
   Query query = getSessao()
     .createQuery("Select entidade from " + classe.getSimpleName() + " entidade Where entidade.id=:id");

   query.setParameter("id", id);
   
   Entidade resultado = null;

   if (!query.getResultList().isEmpty()) {
    resultado = (Entidade) query.getResultList().get(0);
   }

   return resultado;
  } catch (RuntimeException erro) {
   throw erro;
  } finally {
   sessao.close();
  }
 }

Comment: Não costumo usar esse método de "concatenação" para criar as minhas querys. O JPA dá a possibilidade de usar named querys que são querys definidas estaticamente,isso não impede que você passe parâmetros para essas consultas,recomendo que estude sobre Named Query e Facades, que facilita a organização de suas classes para acesso à dados. Recomendo muito o blog uaihebert.com que aborda muito bem o assunto. Para maiores esclarecimentos sobre query's recomendo que faça uma pergunta nova sobre isso. Espero ter ajudado, não esqueça de marcar como "Resposta" se te ajudei nesta pergunta.